# Angular custom pipes returns error with table data

Tags: angular, angular-filters, angular2-custom-pipes

component.html:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
  placeholder="search your products here" 
  name="searchText">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of product| filter: searchText">
      <td>{{obj.id}}</td>
      <td>{{obj.description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

filter.ts:

```
transform(items: any, searchText: string): any[] {
  if (!items || !searchText || searchText === undefined) {
    return items;
  }

  return items.filter(items =>
    items.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase));
}
```

console displays items.description is undefined.

model.ts:

```
export class products{
  id: number;
  description: string;    
}
```

There is no error till the page loads,once I start typing in searchbox,error is displayed.Error is shown in below code.

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
  placeholder="search your issues here" 
  name="searchText">
```

Comment: What is `product`? How is it defined?

Comment: it stores the response of getProducts()

Comment: Your response may not return the `description` field for certain items. I suggest you put a breakpoint at the line where you assign the response to `product` to check this.

Comment: It's also a good idea to add a breakpoint to the `transform` method of your pipe to see what the `items` parameter holds.

Comment: I get the data in object type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling `searchText.toLowerCase` here. You need to call it. Also, you're naming the input and each item as `items`. That's another issue probably.

Change your `transform` implementation to:

```
transform(items: any, searchText: string): any[] {
  if (!items || !searchText || searchText === undefined) {
    return items;
  }

  return items.filter(item =>
    item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));
}
```

Unless of course, it's a typo in your OP.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-pipe-eg?file=src/app/filter.pipe.ts) for your reference.

Comment: Now the error is gone ,but no results are displayed when i search

Comment: Fixed it..Actually I called toLowerCase instead of toLowerCase() previously.

Comment: Hat's off to your expertise Sidd..! Keeping helping us .Thank u so much